# boost::gregorian::date

Tags: visual-c++, linker, boost-date-time

I can't get it to work with visual c++ 2005 and boost 1.43

this simple source code :

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    boost::gregorian::date d();
}
```

gives a link-time error :

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::gregorian::date __cdecl d(void)" (?d@@YA?AVdate@gregorian@boost@@XZ)
```

I've been using other compiled boost libraries like filesystem or thread without problems...

I compiled it using

```
bjam -a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a function prototype, not creating a `boost::gregorian::date` variable. Take off the parentheses.

```
boost::gregorian::date d;
```